Why am I having this issuse while Installing dlib
I am doing a project which requires the face-recognition library for which dlib was needed.
I am having an issue installing "dlib" for a project. The terminal is throwing the following error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [392 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      <string>:125: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
      Building extension for Python 3.11.9 (tags/v3.11.9:de54cf5, Apr  2 2024, 10:12:12) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n0wf3b9r\dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n0wf3b9r\dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n0wf3b9r\dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311 -A x64'
      -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
      -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.22631.
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33811.0     
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33811.0   
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      CMake Deprecation Warning at C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n0wf3b9r/dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:8 (cmake_minimum_required): 
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.

        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


      -- pybind11 v2.10.0
      CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n0wf3b9r/dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:98 (find_package): 
        Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
        are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
        the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n0wf3b9r/dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:50 (find_package)
        C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n0wf3b9r/dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Common.cmake:180 (include)
        C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n0wf3b9r/dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:200 (include)
      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

      -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0/python.exe (found suitable version "3.11.9", minimum required is "3.6")
      -- Found PythonLibs: C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0/libs/python311.lib
      -- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG
      -- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG - Success
      -- Using CMake version: 3.30.0-rc1
      -- Compiling dlib version: 19.24.4
      -- Looking for sys/types.h
      -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
      -- Looking for stdint.h
      -- Looking for stdint.h - found
      -- Looking for stddef.h
      -- Looking for stddef.h - found
      -- Check size of void*
      -- Check size of void* - done
      -- Enabling SSE2 instructions
      -- Searching for JPEG XL
      -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
      -- PkgConfig could not be found, JPEG XL support won't be available
      -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
      -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed        
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found      
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found       
      -- Found Threads: TRUE
      CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n0wf3b9r/dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be/dlib/CMakeLists.txt:652 (find_package):
        Policy CMP0146 is not set: The FindCUDA module is removed.  Run "cmake
        --help-policy CMP0146" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
        set the policy and suppress this warning.

      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

      CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
      -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
      -- Found CUDA, but CMake was unable to find the cuBLAS libraries that should be part of every basic CUDA install. Your CUDA install is somehow broken or incomplete. Since cuBLAS is required for dlib to use CUDA we won't use CUDA.
      -- DID NOT FIND CUDA
      -- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
      -- Searching for FFMPEG/LIBAV
      -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
      -- PkgConfig could not be found, FFMPEG won't be available 
      -- Configuring done (152.3s)
      -- Generating done (0.2s)
      -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n0wf3b9r/dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-311/Release
      Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- /m'
      MSBuild version 17.10.4+10fbfbf2e for .NET Framework       

      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(541,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n0wf3b9r\dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]
        1>Checking Build System
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(541,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n0wf3b9r\dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]      
        Building Custom Rule C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n0wf3b9r/dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be/dlib/CMakeLists.txt
        base64_kernel_1.cpp
        bigint_kernel_1.cpp
        bigint_kernel_2.cpp
        bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp
        entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp
        entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp
        entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp
        entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp
        md5_kernel_1.cpp
        tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp
        unicode.cpp
        test_for_odr_violations.cpp
        fft.cpp
        sockets_kernel_1.cpp
        bsp.cpp
        dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp
        dir_nav_kernel_2.cpp
        dir_nav_extensions.cpp
        fonts.cpp
        linker_kernel_1.cpp
        extra_logger_headers.cpp
        logger_kernel_1.cpp
        logger_config_file.cpp
        misc_api_kernel_1.cpp
        misc_api_kernel_2.cpp
        sockets_extensions.cpp
        sockets_kernel_2.cpp
        sockstreambuf.cpp
        sockstreambuf_unbuffered.cpp
        server_kernel.cpp
        server_iostream.cpp
        server_http.cpp
        multithreaded_object_extension.cpp
        threaded_object_extension.cpp
        threads_kernel_1.cpp
        threads_kernel_2.cpp
        threads_kernel_shared.cpp
        thread_pool_extension.cpp
        async.cpp
        timer.cpp
        stack_trace.cpp
        cpu_dlib.cpp
        tensor_tools.cpp
        image_dataset_metadata.cpp
        mnist.cpp
        cifar.cpp
        global_function_search.cpp
      C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n0wf3b9r\dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be\dlib\geometry\rectangle.h(164,1): warning C4723: potential divide by 0 [C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n0wf3b9r\dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
        kalman_filter.cpp
        auto.cpp
        widgets.cpp
        drawable.cpp
        canvas_drawing.cpp
        style.cpp
        base_widgets.cpp
        gui_core_kernel_1.cpp
        gui_core_kernel_2.cpp
        png_loader.cpp
        save_png.cpp
        jpeg_loader.cpp
        save_jpeg.cpp
        arm_init.c
        filter_neon_intrinsics.c
        palette_neon_intrinsics.c
        png.c
        pngerror.c
        pngget.c
        pngmem.c
        pngpread.c
        pngread.c
        pngrio.c
        pngrtran.c
        pngrutil.c
        pngset.c
        pngtrans.c
        pngwio.c
        pngwrite.c
        pngwtran.c
        pngwutil.c
        adler32.c
        compress.c
        crc32.c
        deflate.c
        gzclose.c
        gzlib.c
        gzread.c
.
.
.
.
.
        File "<string>", line 130, in run
        File "<string>", line 170, in build_extension     
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

The install process always gets stuck on "Building wheel for dlib(pyproject.toml)" for 5 min or so and then throws this gigantic error. I am not able to understand and comprehend what the error says but have tried number of ways to solve it but nothing has worked.
I have tried every option that I found online like creating a virtual environment, installing the .exe file of dlib from github, reinstalling cmake and even tried changing python version to 3.9.11 but the problem still persists.
Thought it was problem with pip so upgraded it too and have tried both pip and pip3, both are not working.
Though I was able to install it through the virtual environment, it had problems in importing the modules.
So if any other suggestions you'll have or is their a problem with my system.
The Python version I am currently working on is 3.11.9.
P.S. - couldn't copy the whole error since it was exceeding the body word limit.

couldn't copy the whole error since it was exceeding the body word limit. there is no information about the error in what you posted

That was the problem the error was like so large I couldn't really pin-point what was causing it. But the solution provided by @tymerius did work. And new to the platform so still learning.


subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.',
'--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[end of output]

CMake Deprecation Warning at C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n0wf3b9r/dlib_94f3ffa0c38b412abab68539f53bd7be/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:8 (cmake_minimum_required): 
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.

This seems to be an error with cmake which is required to install dlib. Try updating it by installing a more recent version as its showing a deprecation warning.
Check this video to see how to download and install in Windows.

it's not, actually. cmake did successfully engage the build. we see successfully built units. eventually, that fails somewhere. that's not an issue with cmake, but with the compilation process.

Though I for sure don't know what was causing the issue but the video solution he provided did work for me so that is much appreciated
